# Deterministic Finite State Automaton (DFA) Exam Q

Tags: dfa, deterministic

The question is:

Design a Deterministic Finite State Automaton (DFA) according to the following
specification:

 Its alphabet is {0, 1}.

 Its language consists of all words with an odd number of 1s.

 0s will not be accepted (even if they are part of the alphabet).

So by this i'm sure it means it'll only accept for example "111" and reject "11"

My first attempt, although it worked (accepts 111 rejects 11) it is accepting 0's
[image]

My second attempt i tried to create a transition table first then the diagram, but q1 had no stage to q2 unless i did my table incorrectly
[image]

My final attempt it..worked i think? But i'm not sure if this diagram is valid
[image]

Could someone give me some insight on which of the 3 diagrams is correct/heading the correct way and how exactly would i solve this/do a transition table

Update: Do you mean like this @Pavel Pája Halbich
[image]

Comment: " Its language consists of all words with an odd number of 1s., 0s will not be accepted (even if they are part of the alphabet)." - does that mean that you need to create FSM accepting words 1^(2n+1), where n >= 0 ?

Comment: I believe it means, your string cannot have 0's in it although it is part of the alphabet, but the machine wont allow 0's. If there is a 0 and ODD amount of 1's. it should still reject it. The accept state must only contain 1's and an odd amount.

Comment: It is wierd with that 0s. They are not accepted anyway (thanks to even count of 1s) and you can't reject character - you are accepting or rejecting whole input, which is word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final diagram is good (but not valid). To get it valid, you need to add transitions:

- q1 -> q2 using 0
- q2 -> q2 using 0,1 (this is classic fail state)

Then you will have 3 states and for each state defined transition to other state, one starting state (q0) and a set of accepting states ({q1}).

Comment: I see, but then although we have q1 -> q2, how do you get from q2 -> q1?

Comment: I've updated the main post at the end, do you mean like this?

Comment: @godlypython If you are saying that if the word on input contains at least on 0, you will reject this word, then you need to create fail state, where you will get using any 0 on input. Then you must never go back to original states (since you are in fail state)

Comment: Ahh it all makes sense now, Thanks a lot